Display 6 decimal places in flow data table
I have a Flow that extracts data via an Apex call into a record collection in the Flow. This collection then displays in a data table for the user to verify and to select any they might want to omit before downloading the collection to a .csv file.
The process works nicely, except that the data returned contains a Percent type field with 6 decimal places, and only 2 are displayed in the flow's data table. On rows where the decimals are minimal eg 0.003456 it looks like the value = 0. This is confusing to the user as they specify to exclude 0 values yet on the table it appears they have not been excluded due to the last 4 decimals places being truncated.
When I download the table's content into a .csv it does contain the full percent field, which is great
I thought of creating a formula field in the flow with the 6 decimals, but I can't specify the collection record's field as the resource for the formula. How on earth do I get it to display the full field value? Or how do I use a Flow formula field for this if I can't specify the collection's field as a resource?
Below is a snip from my Flow's Data Table where everything less than 0.005 shows up as 0% and where 0.005122 displays 0.01% (highlighted). It rounds up/down to 2 decimals:

This is what it actually is and downloads to the .csv:


Worth trying: the UnofficialSf.com DataTable screen component - has more features than OOTB
